# Sed delete everything before and after characters

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cat, terminal-emulator

I'm running on android this

**Command**:

```
dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedApp
```

**Output**:

```
mFocusedApp=ActivityRecord{273535b u0 com.any.some/.app.AnyActivity t5595}
```

**Expected**:

```
com.any.some
```

I need the package name only
Either by sed or another direct command

---

**Edit** (Copied from a comment to an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722851/330217); added to clarify that the resulting string shall be passed as an argument to commands.)

I need to restart the currently focused app so my idea was after grabbing the package name I will stop it by `am stop` and `am start`, example:

```
am stop com.any.some && am start com.any.some
```

Comment: If you wrap your commands and output in triple quotes it makes this much easier to read. Can you edit your question?

Comment: I tried now is it okay

Comment: You can do this with sed if you can write a regular expression for it. I'd need to see more examples of the output to see the patterns. Personally I wouldn't do it in shell or with regular expressions, I'd probably write a simply python script for it. But I can still help if I see more lines.

Comment: `echo mFocusedApp=ActivityRecord{273535b u0 com.any.some/.app.AnyActivity t5595} | cut -d\  -f3 | cut -d/ -f1` yields `com.any.some` but like I say, more sample output would make for a more robust solution.

Comment: nearly the same as your other question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/722859/330217

Comment: The [edit] that was added about "I need to restart the currently focused app..." seems to have absolutely nothing to do with the original question. Remove it and ask a new question if you want to know something about restarting processes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
stdin=$(
  dumpsys activity activities |
    grep mFocusedApp |
    cut -d "{" -f2 |
    cut -d " " -f3 |
    cut -d "/" -f1
)
am force-stop "$stdin" && am start "$stdin"
```

phew thanks guys

Comment: That would match on `mFocusedApp` anywhere on any line rather than just at the start of the line and would match as a substring of longer strings so it's fragile, and it's using 3 unnecessary pipes and commands so it's inefficient.

Comment: May you enhance it please?

Comment: The enhancement to it would be to use one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`:

```
focusApp=$(
  dumpsys activity activities |
    grep -Po '^mFocusedApp=\S+\{\S+ \S+ \K[^\s/]+'
)
```

Standardly:

```
focusApp=$(
  dumpsys activity activities |
    sed -n 's/^mFocusedApp=[^ ]\{1,\}{[^ ]\{1,\} [^ ]\{1,\} \([^\s/]+\).*/\1/p'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
dumpsys activity activities | grep '^mFocusedApp=' | sed 's#.* \([^ ]*\)/.*#\1#'
```

The regular expression matches all non-space characters between   and `/`.

Tested with

```
echo 'mFocusedApp=ActivityRecord{273535b u0 com.any.some/.app.AnyActivity t5595}' |sed 's#.* \([^ ]*\)/.*#\1#'
```

Output:

```
com.any.some
```

(More examples are needed to check if this fits all relevant input.)

---

*Replying to a comment:*

To use the package name for other commands you could save the output in a variable, e.g.

```
package=$(dumpsys activity activities | grep '^mFocusedApp=' | sed 's#.* \([^ ]*\)/.*#\1#')
am stop "$package" && am start "$package"
```

Comment: I need to restart the currently focused app so my idea was after grabbing the package name I will stop it by am stop and am start example am stop com.any.some && am start com.any.some

Comment: @NameF I don't understand what you want to say with this comment. This might be some background information that should go into the question. If you have additional questions, write a new question with a reference to this one and make clear what problem you need help with. From the single example in the question it is not clear if my solution or the `cut` command in a comment to the question will work in other cases.

Comment: Kindly delete the question as it is unclear!

Comment: @NameF The question as it was asked was clear and you got answers to that question. If you want to use the output to restart an app and don't know how to do so then just ask a new question about that after [accepting an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to the question you asked here.

Comment: Alright thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say WHY that should be the output but here's 1 guess at what you might want:

```
dumpsys activity activities| awk -F'[ /]' '/^mFocusedApp=/{print $3}'
com.any.some
```

Comment: Sorry I wanted to have the package name of the currently focused app but it worked for me now thanks!

Comment: Best I can tell thats what this answer gives you, assuming the expected output in your question is "the package name of the currently focused app". You're welcome.