# Restart currently focused app using android ADB

Tags: shell, awk, sed, terminal, android

I tried on android ADB

**Command**:

```
dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedApp
```

**Output**:

```
mFocusedApp=ActivityRecord{u0 com.some.app/.some.AppActivity}
```

**Expected**:

```
com.some.app
```

I need the package name only
Either by sed or another direct command
So I can

**Achieve:**
am stop com.some.app && am start com.some.app

Comment: nearly the same as your other question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/722845/330217

Comment: If this is a followup question to [your previous one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/722845/330217) then [edit] it to show your attempt to use whichever answer you accept from that question in this context and tell us in what way it's not working for you so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ dumpsys activity activities | sed -E '/mFocusedApp/s~[^/]* ([^/]*).*~am stop \1 \&\& am start \1~'
am stop com.some.app && am start com.some.app
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it doesn't work assuming I'm running it by Termux so I'm expecting the output to be com.termux but I'm getting errors those end with this section VisibleActivityProcess:[ ProcessRecord{7d20ba4 30230:com.termux/u0a236}]

Answer (score -1):

stdin=$(dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedApp | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d "/" -f1)
am force-stop "$stdin" && am start "$stdin"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).